# Make footer not clickable list view - Android

Tags: java, android, listview, boolean

I have made a custom list view and here is my current add footer method

```
public void addFooterView(View v) {
    mListView.addFooterView(v);
}
```

What could I add to my custom list view so that, I can make it also not clickable?

I know I need to take in a boolean parameter, but then what do I do with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void addFooterView(View v, boolean clickable) {
   if(!clickable){
         v.setClickable(false);
         v.setFocusable(false);
         v.setEnabled(false);
    }
   mListView.addFooterView(v);
}
```

if it doesn't try this

```
public void addFooterView(View v, boolean clickable) {
   if(!clickable){
         v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            return;
        }
    });
    }
   mListView.addFooterView(v);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't seem to work, for some reason

Comment: check my edit Sir; but try the first one again @timblue

Comment: the edit worked!! weird how the first didn't, thats what I originally tried

Comment: i guess it was waiting for me lol (: @timblue , honestly im glad it did

Answer (score 3):

Use the 2nd method signature:
[addFooterView(View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean))

```
mListView.addFooterView(v, null, false);
```

Comment: This is a custom list view it does not have the method on it

Comment: so `mListView` is not a `ListView`?